# Photoelectric effect under the influence of gravitational time dilation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, gravity, time-dilation, photoelectric-effect

If the energy of a photon increases under the influence of time dilation in a gravitational field, does this have an effect on the photoelectric effect? Does this mean that the photoelectric effect in a specific experiment could take place at the gravitational field of the Earth's surface but not at high altitudes where the time dilation is smaller, because the energy of the photon in question is different and therefore doesn’t reach the appropriate energies for this quantum effect as explained by Einstein?

So would it be possible to imagine a situation in which, due to the gravitational time dilation and corresponding energy increase, the photoelectric effect on the Earth's surface does occur, but at a height with less time dilation the same experiment does not lead to the same result i.e. that the photoelectric effect no longer takes place there?

If not, please explain what is wrong in the setup

Answer (score 5):

You are describing a variation on the [Pound-Rebka experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound%E2%80%93Rebka_experiment).

There is a form of emission/absorbtion of gamma rays by nuclei that has an exceedingly narrow resonance. The resonance is narrow enough to be deployed in a setup for measuring gravitational frequency shift over a distance on the scale of meters, which made it possible to confirm gravitational redshift in a small scale setting.

In the absence of any frequency shift effect the emitter and the absorber must be stationary with respect to each other.

The Pound-Rebka experiment confirmed: when photons have traveled up or down a gravitational potential then in order to hit the resonance the emitter and absorber must have a small velocity relative to each other. (A relative velocity gives a corresponding doppler shift.) It was confirmed: the amount of relative velocity is consistent with the amount of velocity necessary to counteract the effect of gravitational frequency shift.

Answer (score 2):

Experiments conducted in an open system (that is, where external things are allowed to affect our experiment) are easy to misinterpret. So let's keep our experiments closed so we don't get confused. Here, by 'closed' I mean not only is the observer a part of that experiment, but there's no external object even changing the gravity *gradient* within the system. (Yes, I know I've expanded the definition of 'closed'.) For example, if we put an experiment very close to an event horizon, it's an 'open' system in that the energy gradient within the experiment is changed by external things. We can overcome this by saying the experiment (including the observer) is very tiny, such that any changes in the gravity gradient are negligible/undetectable within it.

All closed experiments produce the same result (or statistically the same results when randomness is inherent), regardless of whether they are conducted in a gravity well or not, because all physical laws and constants are the same to the experiment and observer within that closed system no matter where it is. Also, *while* a closed experiment is lowered and raised in a gravity well, an observer within that experiment will continue to see the same result. For example, if I have a box made of perfectly reflecting internal mirrors and I put some photons of a known wavelength in there to bounce around, and then I lower myself with the box into a gravity well, I will see no change in the wavelength of those photons. So, the observer doesn't need to explain why the photons still have the same wavelength any more than does an experiment+observer that was not lowered.

Now consider a closed experiment that contains a planet, a box of light with an observer that follows it while they are lowered and raised, and another observer that remains well above the planet. The observer that follows the box can periodically send some of its photons up to the observer at the top of the gravity well, and also report what they see locally. Of course, the photons sent up get dilated, but the reports of the local observer do not. However, the observer at the top notices a slight slowness in the speech of the observer near the box, and concludes that one explanation is that the observer near the box, and likewise the light within the box, has slowed down.